# Error using the .next method

Tags: rxjs

For several days I have been trying to use the *.next* method to add data.
In trying this :

```
messages: Observable<Message[]>;
const newMessage = new Message(objMessage);
messages.next(newMessage);
```

I have this error:

```
Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Observable<Message[]>'.
```

Does the *.next* method work well in an Observable stream?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `next` is not a function on the Observable. It's a function on the Observer.

You could use a Subject which acts as an Observer and Observable at the same time. So something like this:

```
const messages = new Subject<Message[]>();
const newMessage = new Message(objMessage);
messages.next([newMessage]);
```

As you have an array of `Message`, you also have to use `next` with an array.

For more information: http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html

Comment: OK, thanks. Do you know if there is a method like _.next_ but for Observable?
To add data to a stream, such as a Message collection.

Comment: Yes, perhaps you could use a Subject instead. See updated answer.

Comment: Here's what I did : `messages: Subject<Message[]> = new Subject<Message[]>();            const newMessage = new Message(objMessage);                 this.messages.next([newMessage]);`

However, my message variable contains only one message at a time.

Comment: I don't understand if you still have a problem and in that case, with what?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not very clear..
Yes I always have a problem because I would like my variable _messages_ contains all messages. Out here, _messages_ contains only one message even if I add several messages.

Comment: "[An] observer reacts to whatever item or sequence of items the Observable emits" [source](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html). So, the Observable is a stream of emitted values which the Observer do something with. It seems you want an intermediate model which actually have the correct list of messages and then use the observable to notify changes through subscriptions to somewhere else.

Comment: Yes that's exactly it. My Observable variable has subscriptions in other components.
Here is a post where I explain my problem more clearly:
[How to convert a Subject variable to an Observable variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45754677/8435097)
Do you think this is possible?