# How to convert a Subject variable to an Observable variable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Let me explain. Here is my HTML to display my messages like this:

```
<message
    *ngFor="let message of thread.messages | async"
    [message]="message">
</message>
```

My *thread.messages* variable is an Observable.

```
export class Thread {
  id: string;
  messages: Observable<Message[]> = new Observable<Message[]>();
}
```

In my *addNewMessage()* function, I created a Subject variable to add the new messages in:

```
subjectMessages: Subject<Message[]> = new Subject<Message[]>();

addNewMessage(objMessage: any) : void {
  const newMessage = new Message(objMessage);
  this.subjectMessages.next([newMessage]);
  thread.messages = this.subjectMessages.asObservable();
}
```

I want to convert this *subjectMessages* variable to the *thread.messages* variable. 
But it does not work. My *thread.messages* variable contains an Observable but it does not display anything in my HTML.

However, the display of the last message works :

```
thread.messages.subscribe((message: Message[]) => {
        [thread.lastMessage] = message;
});
```

I despair, do you know where my mistake would be ? Why can I view the last message, not all messages?

Comment: return subjectMessages.asObservable();

Comment: @alehn96
What do you mean ?
Where do you want I return `subjectMessages.asObservable()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, think of what you get in a subscriber as a state. In your code you emit a single message wrapped in an array, `[newMessage]`. The subscribers get these emitted values as stream. If you emit the whole state, the subscribers get access to the whole array of messages.

It doesn't seem right to use both a Subject and an Observable. I haven't tried this but perhaps if you do something like this instead:

```
export class Thread {
  id: string;
  messages: Subject<Message[]> = new Subject<Message[]>();
}

messages: Message[] = new Message[];

addNewMessage(objMessage: any) : void {
  const newMessage = new Message(objMessage);
  messages.push(newMessage);
  thread.messages.next(messages);
}
```

Or perhaps a better approach would be to look at `ReplaySubject` or `BehaviorSubject` which can be used to get previous messages as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!
It works with this : `messages.push(newMessage);
        thread.messages = Observable.of(thread.arrayMessages);`